# Package Publish Web - include IIS settings from IIS manager breaks deployment package build

Tags: web-deployment-project

Im trying to build a deployment package out of VS2010 against a web project and want to include all IIS settings as configured in IIS Manager. However when i enable this i get the following error message

```
Object of type 'manifest' and path 'K:\Sandbox\Web.Crm.Framework\obj\Debug\Package\Web.Crm.Framework.SourceManifest.xml' cannot be created.
One or more entries in the manifest 'sitemanifest' are not valid.
Application '/ISV/Web.Crm.Framework/' does not exist in site 'Default Web Site'.    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets    2855    5   Web.Crm.Framework
```

Now this error makes very little sense as the specified application does exist in Default Web Site. I've checked the spelling. I've tried having ISV as a virtual directory and as an Application and tried with and without the ISV folder.

On the Web page i hae the Project URL set to "http://localhost/ISV/Web.Crm.Framework/"

On the Package/Publish tab IIS web site name is set to "Default Web Site/ISV/Web.Crm.Framework/"

If you need any more information than this please let me know.

Bing/Google search turn up very little on this and the documentation is not really detailed enough. Any help would be appreciated, let me know if you want more details. I'm going to be naught and cross post into the msdn social forums too, get an MVP on the case.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and couldn't find anything on Google to help. So I just tried variations of the values I had in the Project URL and IIS web site name fields, it appears that you need to remove the last "/" from the Project URL value.

So for your project it should be "http://localhost/ISV/Web.Crm.Framework".

Hope this helps!
Nicola