# Web Deploy Packaging fails: Illegal characters in path

Tags: visual-studio-2010, webdeploy

Building a deployment package for a web site works fine for me, but fails for the other members of the team.

Error output from one of my teammates:

> Packaging into C:\tfs-public\SLL -
> Tolkportalen\Main\Source\Deploy\SysTest\OrderPortal.SysTest.zip.
> C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3009,5):
> Error : Web deployment task failed.(Object of type 'manifest' and path
> 'C:\tfs-public\SLL -
> Tolkportalen\Main\Source\Deploy\SysTest\OrderPortal.SysTest.SourceManifest.xml'
> cannot be created.)
>
> Object of type 'manifest' and path 'C:\tfs-public\SLL -
> Tolkportalen\Main\Source\Deploy\SysTest\OrderPortal.SysTest.SourceManifest.xml'
> cannot be created. One or more entries in the manifest 'sitemanifest'
> are not valid. Illegal characters in path. Package failed.

When inspecting, the OrderPortal.SysTest.SourceManifest.xml file has indeed been created at the path mentioned, despite the error message.

One of the failing machines has the source checked out in exactly the same location as on my machine so it shouldn't be a hard coded path issue.

There is another SO question which looks similar, but the error message is not identical and since I'm building a package (which will be copied to a server for deploy) it shouldn't be the same: [Package Publish Web - include IIS settings from IIS manager breaks deployment package build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307501/package-publish-web-include-iis-settings-from-iis-manager-breaks-deployment-pa)

#### EDIT

The package is customized using a wpp.targets file. If removed, it works on the other machines as well, so it might be something with the customizations.

#### Edit

The error has now been isolated to a runCommand statement in wpp.targets that has embedded quotes:

```
<path>net start "Topsi Schedule Service $(Configuration)"</path>
```

Removing the spaces in the service name and the quotes solves the problem. Still no idea why it doesn't fail on my machine though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have the web deploy tool installed on your machine:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569059(v=WS.10).aspx

Comment: Obviously it's possible to build plain vanilla web deploy packages without having web deployed installed on the machine. When using customizations through a wpp.targets file the web deploy package has to be on the *build machine* too.

Answer (score 1):

Try monitoring what it's trying to do with [Sysinternals Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately having Procmon running caused the build to fail. Looks like some kind of file locking issue.